# How to get generated sql query from IQueryable OData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, odata

**I am trying to get sql query which is generated after I pass commands in URL**

*For Example if I hit below URL*

```
http://localhost:57097/Lead?$filter=LeadId eq 9254238 and AssignedToID eq 21987
```

Then I am expecting to get that generated SQL query in c# action which OData generates to fetch data from database.

*Expected Result:*

> select * from lead where LeadId = 9254238 and AssignedToID = 21987